# CSS Grid: How do I put everything on a single row?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to use grid more, but I can’t work out what should be a simple question. How do I put all of the elements in a single row?

That is, I want to emulate the `flex` layout for a single row.

I know I can use `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` in the example below, but I don’t want to set a specific number of columns.

```css
div#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* I know that’s not necessary */
}
div#flex>button {
  flex: 1;
}

div#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
div#grid>button {

}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
  <button>Three</button>
  <button>Four</button>
</div>

<div id="grid">
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
  <button>Three</button>
  <button>Four</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just add `grid-auto-flow: column;` instead : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9midxc

```css
div#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* I know that’s not necessary */
}

div#flex>button {
  flex: 1;
}

div#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

div#grid>button {}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
  <button>Three</button>
  <button>Four</button>
</div>

<div id="grid">
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
  <button>Three</button>
  <button>Four</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that the default value for `grid-auto-flow` is `row` which was my problem. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow